# Can't delete a "list" accidentally created from a "contact" in Sharepoint

Tags: list, sharepoint

A person with designer privileges in a Sharepoint site that I administer accidentally somehow created a list that is just her contact name with the little AD contact icon next to it.
When you click that list (her name), you get a 404 file not found.

I can't see any way to delete it from the available lists.

Answer (score 1):

Try Site Settings > Site Administration:Site libraries and lists. If your list is shown, clicking the Customize link should take you to the List Settings page. You can then click Delete this list under Permissions and Management.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using powershell?

http://spsherm.uptempoconsulting.com/2011/08/deleting-a-sharepoint-list-using-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

Get a copy of [SharePointManager](http://spm.codeplex.com/) to check to see what name/url the list was created with.

From what you say it may be that the list was created with characters that in the url or name that mean it malformed. You may have to go to the object model and script a delete statement using PowerShell.

But first you need to get more information on what the problem with the list is.